# Jessie: How do I make cron create its own log file so it can be monitored in real time?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, cron, logfiles

I know that cron events are stored in `/var/log/syslog` and I can use a command like:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron
```

to see them.

I'd much rather have the system keep a separate cron log file so it doesn't do as much work watching it, as it sorts through all the `syslog` messages to pull out the `cron` notifications.

Then I want to use the `watch` command so I always have an open terminal window showing cron activity.

How do I make the system keep a separate `/var/log/cron.log` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a change in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` with your favorite editor:

```
sudo vi /etc/rsyslog/50-default.conf
```

Find the line that says

```
#cron.*         /var/log/cron.log
```

Remove the `#` from that line. Then restart the service:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

**From then on, all cron-related output will go to `/etc/log/cron.log`**

---

Then to watch it in a terminal window,

**create a `wcron` command script:**

```
echo "#!/bin/bash" >wcron
echo "watch -n 120 tail -n25 /etc/log/cron" >>wcron
chmod +x wcron
sudo cp wcron /usr/sbin
```

**From then on, whenever you want to monitor `cron` in real-time, enter:**

```
wcron
```