# How to control screensaver in Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, screen-saver

**Brand-new Rpi3B+ with a brand-new download of Stretch.**

Made sure everything is up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

---

**I don't mind the automatic screen blanking but would prefer that it ask for a login password when it wakes up.  In Jessie that is easy.**

---

So I went through the normal Jessie-style installation of screensaver controls:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra -y
```

And then, in Preferences, there is new a Screensaver option.

---

HOWEVER, when I click on it, it blinks as it starts up, then simply goes away.

---

So, to properly remove it, I used:

```
sudo apt-get purge xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra -y
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

---

### QUESTION:  How to control screensaver in Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: `xscreensaver` works for me in rapbian stretch. Are you using the official distribution???

Comment: Yep, just downloaded it and went through the update/upgrade/dist-upgrade thing to make extra sure.

Comment: What happens if you type `xscreensaver` in the terminal? Maybe it's something to do with the `3b+`. I don't have one of those yet, just a `3b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gain control of locking Raspbian via the command line**

[Linux xtrlock command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/xtrlock.1x.html)  - Lock your system on command.

Excerpt:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xtrlock
```

The program is blocking to the called process, then returns status 0 after successful unlock.

**To lock your computer, type**

```
xtrlock
```

Command-line arguments:

```
-b    Blank Screen  (only Debian/Raspbian, not Ubuntu)
-f    Fork, then immediately return status 0 to calling process
```

**It changes your mouse pointer into a padlock icon - then waits for you to enter your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

The best part is that active screens continue updating (such as Task Manager or htop or [wcron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/74026/jessie-how-do-i-make-cron-create-its-own-log-file-so-it-can-be-monitored-in-rea/74027#74027fvbg)), until it blanks.

- Lock prevents switching to alternate terminals via the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Fx</kbd> keys.
- Only the Console is locked.
- Network connections are still enabled.

---

**To make it easier, create the `xl` command script:**

```
(shebang)/bin/bash
xtrlock -f

chmod +x xl
sudo cp xl /usr/sbin
```

**To lock your computer, type**

```
xl
```

---

**To prevent screen blanking, do this one time:**

[Disable screen blanking in X-Windows on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/disable-screen-blanking-in-x-windows-on-raspbian/5145#5145)

Excerpt:

Edit `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and add these three lines:

```
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
```

Save it then Reboot or log out.

---